# Secure Boot on imx6ul using HABv4

Tags: linux, u-boot, imx6

I am currently working on performing a secure boot on the imx6ul using HABv4. I followed the steps provided in the following document.

http://marc.info/?l=u-boot&m=139227973004718&q=p5

After performing all the steps I have described below, I typed hab_status in the U-boot command prompt. Then I get the HAB Events I have shown below.  The only step I did not perform is fusing the SRK table. I would like to know the following information:

1. Is it a must to fuse the SRK table during the development stage?
2. From where can I find the load address that has to specify in the csf file? I used the following value defined in the Uboot configuration file. The document AN4581 (Rev.0,10/2012) describes that start* = TEXT_BASE and that it is defined in the config.mk file. However, config.mk file is not available in my U-boot folder (Probably because I am using a newer version).

   ```
               #define CONFIG_SYS_TEXT_BASE 0x87800000
   ```

AN4581(Rev. 1, 10/2015) does not provide any information regarding this.

3. How does the Uboot knows the starting pointer of cfs? Should we specify it in any other location?
4. I have specified the steps I performed below. Let me know whether anything I am doing wrongly.

**Steps Performed:**
Please see the steps performed below.

1. Built u-boot.imx enabling the secure mode.
2. Generated all root public key files and corresponding hash.
3. Created csf file with the following content. Content of the file is attached at the end.
4. My u-uboot.imx file is 0x60830. I extended it to 0x61000 using the following command.

   ```
              objcopy -I binary -O binary --pad-to 0x61000 --gap-fill=0x5A u-boot.imx u-boot-pad.imx
   ```
5. Then I generated csf.bin file using the command below.

   ```
             ./cst -o u-boot_csf.bin -i uboot.csf
   ```
6. Merged image and csf data using the command below.

   ```
             cat u-boot-pad.imx u-boot_csf.bin  > u-boot-signed.imx
   ```
7. Then extended the final image to 0x63000

   ```
             objcopy -I binary -O binary --pad-to 0x63000 --gap-fill=0x5A u-boot-signed.imx u-boot-signed-pad.imx
   ```
8. The length of the block is calculated as: Length = u-boot-pad.imx (0x61000) - IVT_OFFSET (0x400).
   And added 400 to the starting address as shown below.

   ```
          #        Address    Offset Length Data File Path

          Blocks = 0x87800400 0x400 0x00060C00 "u-boot-pad.imx"
   ```

**HAB Events:**

```
HAB Configuration: 0xf0, HAB State: 0x66
--------- HAB Event 1 -----------------
event data:
        0xdb 0x00 0x1c 0x42 0x33 0x18 0xc0 0x00
        0xca 0x00 0x14 0x00 0x02 0xc5 0x00 0x00
        0x00 0x00 0x0d 0x34 0x87 0x80 0x04 0x00
        0x00 0x06 0x0c 0x00
--------- HAB Event 2 -----------------
event data:
        0xdb 0x00 0x14 0x42 0x33 0x0c 0xa0 0x00
        0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x87 0x7f 0xf7 0xd0
        0x00 0x00 0x00 0x20
--------- HAB Event 3 -----------------
event data:
        0xdb 0x00 0x14 0x42 0x33 0x0c 0xa0 0x00
        0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x87 0x7f 0xf7 0xfc
        0x00 0x00 0x01 0xf0
--------- HAB Event 4 -----------------
event data:
        0xdb 0x00 0x14 0x42 0x33 0x0c 0xa0 0x00
        0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x87 0x7f 0xf7 0xf0
        0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
--------- HAB Event 5 -----------------
event data:
        0xdb 0x00 0x14 0x42 0x33 0x0c 0xa0 0x00
        0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x87 0x80 0x00 0x00
        0x00 0x00 0x00 0x04



Command Sequency File Description:
#Illustrative Command Sequence File Description
[Header]
Version = 4.1
Hash Algorithm = sha256
Engine = ANY
Engine Configuration = 0
Certificate Format = X509
Signature Format = CMS
[Install SRK]
File = "../crts/SRK_1_2_3_4_table.bin"
# Index of the key location in the SRK table to be installed
Source index = 0
[Install CSFK]
# Key used to authenticate the CSF data
File = "../crts/CSF1_1_sha256_2048_65537_v3_usr_crt.pem"
[Authenticate CSF]
[Install Key]
# Key to install
File= "../crts/IMG1_1_sha256_2048_65537_v3_usr_crt.pem"
# Target key slot in HAB key store where key will be installed
Target Index = 2
# Key slot index used to authenticate the key to be installed
Verification index = 0
[Authenticate Data]
#        Address    Offset Length Data File Path
Blocks = 0x87800400 0x400 0x00060C00 "u-boot-pad.imx"

# Key slot index used to authenticate the image data
Verification index = 2
```

Best Regards

Comment: Hello were you able to solve your problem. I am also using i.MX6UL and facing same problem.

Comment: @prattom did u guys succeed doing this ? I finaly got it working.

Comment: @thilinaur It would really be nice of you if you could explain the steps here in answer. Thanks in advance!